# What happens exactly when we use Nginx to deploy an Angular application?

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm new to the concept of deployment and Nginx. Why do we use nginx if we can simply run the application in a container?

What I mean is the following. Before using Nginx, we used to create a docker image that installs the dependencies and then runs the application on a specific port. After using nginx, we provided the compiled data of the angular application to the conf file of nginx which still runs on a specific port on the localhost for now. What are the differences between the two cases here ?

I just want a simple and general explanation of the usage of nginx in the case of angular applications

Comment: Because nginx can handle a high volume of connections and it is commonly used as a reverse proxy and load balancer.

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, you would not use nginx to deploy something. Which kind of container do you mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase What I mean is the following. Before using Nginx, we used to create a docker image that installs the dependencies and then runs the application on a specific port. After using nginx, we provided the compiled data of the angular application to the conf file of nginx which still runs on a specific port on the localhost for now. What are the differences between the two cases here ?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you ask your colleagues for the reason to switch this? They might know best why this happened

Comment: @NicoHaase I appreciate your help. If you have anything to say about the question, please let me know.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.